# Scaling Property of Hausdorff Measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

A book I'm reading discusses the proof of the following statement:

> Let $S$ be a similarity transformation of scale factor $\lambda > 0$. If $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then $$\mathcal{H}^s(S(F)) = \lambda \mathcal{H}^s(F)$$

The proof follows:

> If $\{U_i\}$ is a $\delta$-cover of $F$ then ${S(U_i)}$ is a $\lambda\delta$-cover of $S(F)$, so $$\sum |S(U_i)|^s = \lambda^s \sum|U_i|^s$$ so $$\mathcal{H}_{\lambda \delta}^s(S(F)) \leq \lambda \mathcal{H}_\delta^s(F)$$Letting $\delta \rightarrow 0$ gives the $\leq$ direction. **Replacing $S$ by $S^{-1}$ and so $\lambda$ by $1/\lambda$ and $F$ by $S(F)$ gives the opposite inequality.**

1. I dont understand why from $\sum |S(U_i)|^s = \lambda^s \sum|U_i|^s$ we can't conclude $\mathcal{H}_{\lambda \delta}^s(S(F)) = \lambda \mathcal{H}_\delta^s(F)$
2. Even if I wanted to follow the instructions in the last sentence, I'm getting a little mixed up where everything should go in the argument marked in bold.

Comment: The intuition is that if $\{U_i\}$ is an *optimal* $\delta$-cover of $F$, then $\{S(U_i)\}$ is a $\lambda\delta$-cover of $S(F)$, but it may not be an *optimal* cover.  It may be possible to find a better cover.

Comment: If I scale and rotate an optimal cover on $F$, it won't be an optimal cover on $S(F)$?

Comment: Perhaps.  Can  you prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $H^s_\delta$ reads:
$$
H_\delta^s(F) := \inf\{ \sum |U_i|^s: U_i \text{ is a } \delta\text{-cover of } F \}.
$$

The equality $\sum |S(U_i)|^s = \lambda^s \sum |U_i|^s$ gives
$$
\inf\{ \sum |S(U_i)|^s: U_i \text{ is a } \delta\text{-cover of } F \}  = \inf\{ \lambda^s \sum |U_i|^s: U_i \text{ is a } \delta\text{-cover of } F \} = \lambda^sH^s_\delta(F).
$$
Notice that the infima on the lefthand side is a priori not over all covers $\lambda\delta$-covers of $S(F)$ just the ones who can be written as an image of $S$. From that observation we derive
$$H^s_{\lambda\delta}(S(F)) = \inf\{ \sum |V_i|^s: V_i \text{ is a } \lambda\delta\text{-cover of } S(F) \} \leq \inf\{ \sum |S(U_i)|^s: U_i \text{ is a } \delta\text{-cover of } F \}.$$

This inequalities put together give
$$
H^s_{\lambda\delta}(S(F)) \leq \lambda^sH^s_\delta(F).
$$
Letting $\delta$ tend to $0$ you get
$$
H^s(S(F)) \leq \lambda^sH^s(F).
$$
Applying above results also to $S^{-1}$ yields the inequalitiy chain
$$
H^s(S(F)) \leq \lambda^sH^s(F) = \lambda^sH^s(S^{-1}(S(F))) \leq \lambda^s \frac{1}{\lambda}^sH^s(S(F)) = H^s(S(F))
$$
and therefore
$$
H^s(S(F)) = \lambda^sH^s(F).
$$

Comment: Maybe a thing to note is that you can prove it via bijectivity directly. But normally you do not necessarly have bijectivity so doing it this way provides a bit more insight in how the Hausdorff measure behaves for functions which have 'just' Lipschitz properties, etc.

Comment: Almost there, the chain of inequalities is still confusing to me

Comment: oh is it forcing equalities throughout the string?

Comment: You know that $S^{-1}$ is a similarity transformation with parameter $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Applying the result we get before the inequality this means: $H^s(S^{-1}(E)) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}^s H^s(E)$ for all $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. In the chain you use this result for $E = S(F)$.